# Expressing length as Angular Measurements

Tags: euclidean-geometry, unit-of-measure

When an angle is drawn, it is not exactly as measured, as a negligible part of that angle is covered up by the lines making the angle.
If we take the thickness of the line and measure it using angular measurements(for instance degree), could we use the same for expressing lengths using a combination of length and angle? (x cm as 5 degrees (from a distance y cm from a fixed point)
But if in a measuring instrument(say protractor), 1 degree = 1mm (or any other unit), that would be the same as measuring 5 cm as 50mm.
So can angles and lengths be considered the different sides of the same coin. Are angles and lengths equivalent

This seems awfully similar to the relation l=rθ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

I'm not sure if I understand your question fully; it's unclear what you mean when you say "measure the thickness of the line using angular measurements."

As you point out, $\ell = r \theta$ measures the length of a circular arc that rotates $\theta$ radians and has a radius $r$. However, note that although radians are a measurement, they are in fact unitless! It sounds crazy, but it actually comes from the definition:

> [the radians traversed by an arc] are equal to the ratio of the length of the enclosed arc to the length of the circle's radius.

This means they are defined in terms of (length / length) and are have no unit. This is in contrast to lengths, which do. Put another way, the above equation is the same as saying that, by definition, the radians of an arc are given by $\theta = \ell / r$.

So, no, *angles and lengths are not equivalent*. In the specific case that you have a circular arc that traverses some angle, you can use the radius of the circle to relate it to a length.

Comment: I think they are referring to the errors made when measuring angles drawn by varying thickness of pens.

Comment: Yeah. I interpreted that to mean that if you draw a circle with a pencil of fixed thickness, every angle has a unique arc length. And they were wondering if that meant angles and lengths could be equated more generally.